# MySQL connection drops after some time

Tags: mysql, node.js, sockets

I am working with websocket which is built with Node.js. I have added some basic interacting with the database to the script (simple insert/update/select queries). The problem is after some time ~30 seconds the script crashes with this error:

```
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/home/admin/web/ohrana.ua/public_html/webrtc/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/admin/web/ohrana.ua/public_html/webrtc/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/admin/web/ohrana.ua/public_html/webrtc/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1223:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (/home/admin/web/ohrana.ua/public_html/webrtc/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Protocol._delegateError (/home/admin/web/ohrana.ua/public_html/webrtc/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
    at Protocol.end (/home/admin/web/ohrana.ua/public_html/webrtc/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:116:8)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/admin/web/ohrana.ua/public_html/webrtc/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  fatal: true,
  code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
}
```

I have googled this and found this solution to add this part of code into the script:

```
mysqlc.on('error',err=>{
    if(err.code==='PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'){
        mysqlc=null;
        mysqlc=mysql.createConnection(db_params)
    }
    else throw err;
});
```

However it didn't help. After I have added this code to the script and it seems like the time between when script gets started and crashed has increased (now it is like 5-10 mins) but anyway the script crashes with the same error.

Then I have googled another solution which didn't help too. It was said to add

```
connectTimeout:24*60*60*1000
```

into params which I use when initializing connection into mysql.createConnection()

However it didn't help too. So I am stuck at this point and don't know what to do and how I can deal with this error. Need some advice.

Comment: increase or add the wait_timeout and idle_time out i am at the momonet unsure which will help you so use bith and add 280800 that is 8 hoirs

Comment: Please update your question to include the code showing how your connection (`mysqlc`) is initialized and which options you're using. Also provide an example of the query which generated this error.